# Trying to make a list of all the images for preprocessing but getting an error

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, data-mining

I am trying to add all the images in the list from my computer in the jupyter notebook. But after creating an object name as class_name and put it equal to covid, I created a sourse_dir file and destination_dir file, and when I run it shows no error. but when I try to make a list of source_dir files I get an error the system can not find the path. does anyone can help. please see the attached image of my jupyter notebook and path of source_dir file. . can anyone help me why I am getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNRR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsBl8.png)

Comment: Look at the path that is printed in the code. Then look at the actual path of the folder. Notice they're not the same...

Comment: I tried can you write what exactly should be the path be?@xdurch

Comment: @kiran The last folder name is wrong`CT_COVIDcovid` the last covid "small letters", print your path to check.